# (Change Datasource) Prompt for Server and SQL Server database within Crystal Reports Viewer, Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm using SAP Crystal Reports 2016 with the Visual Studio plugin, along with Visual Studio 2015.

What I've done is created a simple MDI application using C# which contains multiple Crystal Reports Viewer forms which open an embedded report in a child window when the menu item is clicked. This application will sit on our development server and be used to run reports against client databases that get sent to us with problems.

Here's the issue. We've got multiple instances (and versions) of SQL Server running and we are getting multiple test databases daily which of course will be named differently. The reports are looking for a specific database only.

What I would like to do, is either on form load or via a button click, be able to have a box prompt the user for server and database name. For example:

```
SQLServer\SuperCoolInstance
My_Cool_Database
```

The report would then connect to that database and display relevant information.

Any idea on how I could accomplish this? Second best scenario would be to have something like an XML file that contains the server and database and the program looks at that when launching. Even though we'd have to edit the XML whenever we wanted to change datasources it would be something! I wouldn't know how to pursue that avenue either though.

I would think that this must be possible because at a previous company that I worked for, they actually sent compiled Crystal Reports (in exe format) to clients to run on THEIR systems and it looked to an already existing XML file.

Thanks very much in advance for any ideas or guidance.

Cheers.

EDIT - I thought I should point out that all the SQL Server databases that this would run on would have identical schema but different data obviously. Not that this probably matters for this particular question, but just in case. :)

Comment: Just ask, is you database has the same data with the other server? if not you need to have a specific report to each specific DB Server.

Comment: Hi reds. I don't understand your response. In my post I mentioned that any database is run the reports against will have identical schemas but will have different data.

Comment: What do yo mean this one?Here's the issue. We've got multiple instances (and versions) of SQL Server running and we are getting multiple test databases daily which of course will be named differently. The reports are looking for a specific database only.